Closed form for the area under $ f(x):=\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{\pi(Nx)}{\pi(N)} $
Define a function $f:\Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q$ by the following $$ f(x):=\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{\pi(Nx)}{\pi(N)} $$
where $\pi(\cdot)$ is the prime counting function and $N\in \Bbb N.$ I would like to find a closed form for the area under this function, which can be found to be exactly $27/40$ when setting $N=10$ and which is rational for finite $N$.

Is there a closed form for the area under $f(x)$ between zero and one?

I thought this area could be $1/2$ because from my analysis it looked to approach that value but I don't know for sure.

What do you mean by “area under the curve” if your function is only defined on the rationals?

@kieransquared I suppose OP is referring to the area under the "staircase" in the limit.

Since $\pi(N)\sim N/\ln N$ by the prime number theorem,
$$
f(x)
= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\pi(Nx)}{\pi(N)}
= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Nx/\ln(Nx)}{N/\ln N}
= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x\,\ln N}{\ln N+\ln x}
= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{1+\ln x/\ln N}
= x
$$
for $x\ge0$, so you should have $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=1/2$.
